# Extracting month day from datetime column to plot a seasonal line chart with Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Sample of Dataframe I'm dealing with as follows.

`df_sub = pd.DataFrame([[2020-01-01, 2019-01-02, 2018-01-15, 2017-01-18], [2019, 2018, 2017, 2016], [15, 9, 39, 20]], columns=['GAME_DATE', 'SEASON', 'PTS')`

- There are approx 20-30 data points for GAME_DATE and POINTS within each SEASON. This will vary depending on what is selected from other dataframe, DF
- GAME_DATE is a datetime column

I want to create a single plot with game_date on x-axis, points on y-axis and one line plotted for each season.

Tried the following but does not achieve what I want as it plots each seasons data sequentially with gaps for when there is a break. I am wanting each season plotted on a different line whilst utilising a consistent x-axis of one year rather than extending out for each year.

`ax = sns.lineplot(x = 'GAME_DATE', y = 'PTS', hue = 'SEASON', markers = True, dashes = False, data = df_sub)`

Figured I need to extract month and day from GAME_DATE for the X-AXIS as the SEASON already takes care of the year/seasonality component

```
df_sub['SEASONAL'] = df_sub['GAME_DATE'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')
```

this does the job in terms of extracting month, day however when plotting with the following - the plot created is an absolute mess

```
ax = sns.lineplot(x = 'SEASONAL', y = 'PTS', hue = 'SEASON', markers = True, dashes = False, data = df_sub)
```

Thinking I need to convert df_sub['SEASONAL'] to a datetime column from its current type as a non-null object? Trying the following however inserts a year back into each entry of the seasonal column (the year 1900..uhhh)

```
df_sub['SEASONAL'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sub['SEASONAL'], format = "%m-%d")
```

Appreciate any assistance

Answer (score 0):

String datetime does not work when plotting. You can convert string datetime to epoch time in milliseconds.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

# make epoch datetime
list_date = ['2020-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2018-01-15', '2017-01-18']
dates = [pd.to_datetime(d) for d in list_date]
dates_epoch = [(t- pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta('1ms') for t in dates]

# create dataframe
df_sub = pd.DataFrame([dates_epoch, 
                       [2019, 2018, 2017, 2016], 
                       [15, 9, 39, 20]
                      ])
df_sub = df_sub.T
df_sub.columns=['GAME_DATE', 'SEASON', 'PTS']

# print(df_sub)
#        GAME_DATE  SEASON  PTS
# 0  1577836800000    2019   15
# 1  1546387200000    2018    9
# 2  1515974400000    2017   39
# 3  1484697600000    2016   20

sns.lmplot(x='GAME_DATE', y='PTS', hue= 'SEASON', data=df_sub,lowess=True)

# get current axis
ax = plt.gca()
# get current xtick labels
xticks = ax.get_xticks()
# convert all xtick labels to selected format from ms timestamp
ax.set_xticklabels([pd.to_datetime(tm, unit='ms').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for tm in xticks], rotation=50)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm not sure this is your desired result, but hope this help.

---

**Edit** To answer the comments...

For your case,

`pd.to_datetime(df_sub['SEASONAL'].iloc[0], unit='ms').strftime('%m-%d')`

will work.

`pd.to_datetime()` makes Timestamp with pandas. I think this way is useful to manage time-data easily.

```
# put some timedata, mostly string but int with unit is ok
pd.to_datetime(1577836800000, unit='ms')
# Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')
pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01')
# Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')
```

and with `strftime(format)`, convert timestamp from string with format.

```
pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01').strftime('%m-%d')
# '01-01'
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback although this did not reach my desired result. I think my issue lies in the GAME_DATE series column in df_sub dataframe being a string like you say that is then causing issues with plotting. 

`df_sub['SEASONAL'] = df['GAME_DATE'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')` <-- extracts month and day information I want but as a non-null object. I try to convert to datetime (will help with plotting?) with the following 
`df_sub['SEASONAL'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sub['SEASONAL'], format = %m-%d')` however this then adds the year 1900 to each value, but I did not include %Y in format?

Comment: I've added in answer post. Please try.

Comment: Thanks again, I have tried the following 
`df_sub['SEASONAL'] = pd.to_datetime(df['GAME_DATE']).strftime('%m-%d')` received following error -- series object has no attribute strftime. 

Then tried `df_sub['SEASONAL'] = pd.to_datetime(player['GAME_DATE'].iloc(0), unit = 'ms').strftime('%m-%d')` received following error --  Argument 'values' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got _iLocIndexer)

Comment: iloc[0], not (0)

Comment: apologies for the oversight on my part. Have applied the following `pd.to_datetime(df_sub['SEASONAL'].iloc[0], unit='ms').strftime('%m-%d')` format looks fine however the first rows value in the SEASONAL column in df_sub is then repeated across subsequent rows. I don't have that issue using this though the `df_sub['SEASONAL'] = df_sub['GAME_DATE'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')` however back to the issue of it adding the year 1900 to each date when applying `df_sub['SEASONAL'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sub['SEASONAL'], format='%m-%d')`

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot reproduce your df_sub['SEASONAL'] using .dt. with df_sub['GAME_DATE']. Maybe definition of df_sub is not string?

Comment: Please provide `df_sub['SEASONAL']` in `pd.to_datetime(df_sub['SEASONAL'], format = "%m-%d")`.

Comment: df_sub is a slice of df, maybe this causes issues? so I try on df with the following, note: df['GAME_DATE'] is initially a non-null object.
`df['GAME_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['GAME_DATE'], format = "%Y-%m-%d")

df['SEASONAL'] = df['GAME_DATE'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')

df['SEASONAL'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SEASONAL'], format = "%m-%d", errors = 'coerce')`

which results in all entries in df['SEASONAL'] having dates with starting with the year 1900, in format - %Y-%m-%d

Comment: I can’t reproduce if you don’t provide value. What is initial df[‘GAME_DATE‘]?